# added 3 tree views in my master page,but they r not visible

Tags: .net, asp.net, treeview

I added 3 tree views in my master page, i want them to show them based on different conditions, but they are not visible on other pages.

Code:

```
    Dim TreeView1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView = New TreeView
    Dim TreeView2 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView = New TreeView
    Dim TreeView3 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView = New TreeView
    Dim str As String = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("UserType")
    Select Case (str)
        Case "Faculty"
            Response.Write("Faculty")
            TreeView1.Visible = True
            Exit Select
        Case "Admin"
            Response.Write("Admin")
            TreeView2.Visible = True
            Exit Select
        Case "Student"
            Response.Write("Student")
            TreeView3.Visible = True
            Exit Select
    End Select
```

Please let me know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Controls.Add(TreeView1)`.

If this doesn't help, please provide more detail.

Comment: The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.

Comment: second answer give this error

Control 'ctl00_ctl02' of type 'TreeView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: its give error 
Control 'ctl00_ctl02' of type 'TreeView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Did you read the error?  Put it inside a `<form runat="server">`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
Dim TreeView1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView = New TreeView
Dim TreeView2 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView = New TreeView
Dim TreeView3 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView = New TreeView
Dim str As String = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("UserType")
Select Case (str)
    Case "Faculty"
        Response.Write("Faculty")
        TreeView1.Visible = True
        Page.Controls.Add(Treeview1)
        Exit Select
    Case "Admin"
        Response.Write("Admin")
        TreeView2.Visible = True
        Page.Controls.Add(Treeview2)
        Exit Select
    Case "Student"
        Response.Write("Student")
        TreeView3.Visible = True
        Page.Controls.Add(Treeview3)
        Exit Select
End Select
```

Comment: its give error 

The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.

Answer (score 0):

This question is fairly old, but an answer was never marked on it.  I believe that it is a common enough problem to place an answer out on Stack Overflow.

Rather than calling

```
Page.Controls.Add(Treeview1)
```

try calling

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add(Treeview1)
```

adding it to the Form and not directly to the Page.

David

Comment: Interestingly enough when I use the "Controls" collection (`Controls.Add(Treeview1)`) I get the same error _"Control 'ctl02' of type 'Treeview1' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."_ though my code obviously has a `<form runat='server' id='form1'>` since it works normally.